# Import module works with Eclipse but not in command Line

Tags: python

I have a very simple program in python with this structure:

```
HelloWorldPython
   src
      code
         __init__.py
         Main.py
         Secondary.py
```

I have 2 module in 1 package. This is Main.py:

```
from code.Secondary import Secondary

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Class Main")
    secondary=Secondary()
    secondary.printText()
```

and this is Secondary.py:

```
class Secondary:

    def printText(self):
        print("Secondary Class")
```

Everything works fine when I lauch the program from Eclipse. But when I lauch the program from command line, I obtain this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from code.Secondary import Secondary
ImportError: No module named Secondary
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the other module is in the same directory, you don't need to qualify it. Therefore, you simply need to do:

```
from Secondary import Secondary
```

The reason why it works in Eclipse is because Eclipse has added `src` to the `PYTHON_PATH` too.